# merging two data frames with conditions

Tags: r

I'd like to merge 2 `data.frame`s named `df1` and `df2`, so I want to take rows from `df2` and add them in `df1` if the values from the 2 specific columns match, otherwise I'd keep the rows from `df1`. In other words, I don't want to have duplicated data. Here's an example from a long `data.frame`s:

```
df1 <- data.frame(
    X = c(18,20,21,27,50),
    Y = c(4,5,6,9,8),
    Z = c(1,0.3,0.4,0.7,0.9)
)

df2 <- data.frame(
    X = c(20,40,50,),
    Y = c(1,4,8),
    Z = c(2.2,0.3,0.6)
)
```

Since the row 5 from `df1` and the row 3 from `df2` match in `X` and `Y`, I replace it, so I don't have to take `Z` in consideration.

So my `df` would be like this:

```
> mergedf
   X Y   Z
1 18 4 1.0
2 20 5 0.3
3 21 6 0.4
4 27 9 0.7
5 50 8 0.9 #The row from df1 instead of df2
6 20 1 2.2
7 40 4 0.3
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you just want `rbind` or `rbind.data.frame`, then `unique` on the desired columns, and use those `rownames` to index:

```
df3 <- rbind.data.frame(df1, df2)
df3[rownames(unique(df3[, -3])), ]

##    X Y   Z
## 1 18 4 1.0
## 2 20 5 0.3
## 3 21 6 0.4
## 4 27 9 0.7
## 5 50 8 0.9
## 6 20 1 2.2
## 7 40 4 0.3
```

Answer (score 1):

This should work

```
mm<-merge(df1, df2, all=T, by=c("X","Y"))
mm<-transform(mm,
    Z=ifelse(is.na(Z.x), Z.y, Z.x),
    Z.x=NULL,
    Z.y=NULL)
mm
#    X Y   Z
# 1 18 4 1.0
# 2 20 1 2.2
# 3 20 5 0.3
# 4 21 6 0.4
# 5 27 9 0.7
# 6 40 4 0.3
# 7 50 8 0.9
```

Here we merge all values from both data sets, then we fill in the missing `Z` values from the first table with those of the second table. Then we clean up the temp columns.